# How can I use the colors I want in a plot with different categories?

Tags: plotly-python

I have the following script

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

# Your data
data = {
    'X': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'Y': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
    'Cat': ["cat", "dog", None, None, "dog", "dog", None, None, "cat", "dog"]
}

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Category'] = df['Cat'].fillna('Normal')

# Map colors based on 'Cat' values
# color_map = {'cat': 'red', 'dog': 'blue', None: 'grey'}
# df['Color'] = df['Cat'].map(color_map)

print(df)

# Create scatter plot with colors
fig = px.scatter(df, x='X', y='Y', color='Category', hover_data=['Category'], labels={'Color': 'Category'}, title='Scatter Plot with Colors')
# fig = px.scatter(df, x='X', y='Y', color='Color', hover_data=['Cat'], labels={'Color': 'Category'}, title='Scatter Plot with Colors')

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

With this I got

[image]

which is ok I suppose, but I would really want to be able to set the colors I want

However when I uncomment the color_map and I use the commented scatter

```
color_map = {'cat': 'red', 'dog': 'blue', None: 'grey'}
df['Color'] = df['Cat'].map(color_map)
fig = px.scatter(df, x='X', y='Y', color='Color', hover_data=['Cat'], labels={'Color': 'Category'}, title='Scatter Plot with Colors')
```

I got this
[image]

which makes thing worse:

1. The labels are now wrong
2. The red dot is colored blue (all the rest are wrong too)

So how can I correctly set the colors?